# Transformation of a sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I want to prove the following or a similar result: For $1\le k \le n$
\begin{align}&1-\sum\limits_{j=k+1}^n\binom nj(1-x)^jx^{n-j}~~~~~~(1)\\
\underset{\text{wrong}}{\overset{\text{maybe}}=}~&1-\sum\limits_{j=n-k-1}^n\binom njx^j(1-x)^{n-j}~~(2)\end{align}
I think that the equation as written here is wrong, but I want to get a result similar to this. (That means I want to transfer it to a sum with limits like in (2) or alternatively $\sum\limits_{j=n-k}^n$)

I tried applying the binomial theorem
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^{n-k}y^k=(x+y)^n$$
and the symmetry of the binomial coefficient
$$\binom nj=\binom n{n-j},$$
but didn't yield any of the desired results, yet.

Comment: If you put $y=1-x$ in the binomial theorem, your first sum becomes $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^k\binom nj(1-x)^jx^{n-j}$$. Then use the change of indices $j=n-l$.

Comment: If I didn't make any mistakes the result would be
$$\sum\limits_{j=n-k}^n\binom{n}{j-n+k}(1-x)^{j-n+k}x^{2n+k-j}$$
which contains the desired sum limits but not
$$\binom njx^j(1-x)^{n-j}.$$

Comment: I  agree with the sum limits in the result. Now you have $\binom{n}{j}=\binom{n}{n-l}=\binom{n}{l}$ if I am not wrong of course....

Comment: The rules of index shifting are
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k) = \sum_{k=1+z}^{n+z}(a_{k-z})$$
Therefore I don't think you can just substitute the variable.

Comment: Well, I do not understand. We have $\sum\limits_{j=0}^k\binom nj(1-x)^jx^{n-j}$ as your first sum. I put $j=n-l$. To have $j$ from $0$ to $k$, we take $l$ from $n-k$ to $n$. Now we replace $j$ by $n-l$ in the sum. Do you agree ?

Comment: Okay, now I got it. I didn't understand what you mean with $l$ at first and didn't use the symmetry of the binomial coefficient in my post.
Thank you for helping!